# What is the difference between doGet and doPost?

Tags: java, servlets

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
}
```

and

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTTP protocal GET and POST are type of request headers. So whenever a GET type of request is recieved by server, doGet() method is invoked at the backend. Same goes for POST, doPost() is invoked.

Example:
This will invoke doGet when html form is submitted.

```
<form method="GET" action="servletname">
```

This will invoke doPost()

```
<form method="POST" action="servletname">
```

There are more request type headers like put, delete that are used for implementing REST api.